# Odd heisenbug in CSS layout

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Ok I have a really weird CSS issue that I was wondering could anyone suggest an explanation for.

Steps to reproduce:

Open Chrome and navigate to http://www.mcwhinneys.com/media
The gallery of photos should be out of alignment, off to the right by about 50-70px
Open the Developer console in chrome

Expected Result:

i do this to inspect the css expecting to see why the images are off to the side, fixing the css and moving on.

Actual Results:

The gallery of images pops into alignment when the developer tools open.

Anyone know why this might happen? It seems as if the css is fine when I inspect it but it definitely doesn't render correctly until the console has been opened.

Comment: The alignment looks fine to me. Chrome v19.0.1055.1

Comment: +1 for heisenbug, -1 for not seeing it in Chrome.

Comment: +0.5 for Heisenbug, +0.5 for seeing it in current stable release of Chrome (17.0.963.56). Note that you need to inspect the element (on Michael's page *any* element - `<html>` is enough) - it's not enough to just bring up the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the actual cause for the wrong layout is the combination of `text-align: center` on your `ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box` (I'll call that *box* from now on) with `position: absolute` + `display: inline-block` on the inner `ngg-gallery-thumbnail` (I'll call that *thumb*).

It goes like this:

- We apply `text-align: center` to *box*. This will cause it to center its inline children. It does this (conceptually) by placing each child's left edge at the current "text cursor" position (which, importantly, starts out at *box*'s center), then moving it towards the left to "recenter" it. This is - also importantly - *box*'s "job".
- We declare the *thumb* as `inline-block`. This will (among other things) cause it to follow `text-align` of its parent, meaning that - at this point in time - it's centered.
- We then declare *thumb* `position: absolute`. This will take it out of the flow, positioning its left edge at the same point *where it originally would be* - because we're not specifying `left`/`right`.

The "naive" interpretation of this would be that it's still at the center of *box*, and everything would be fine, but we get a "side effect"...

- Because we took *thumb* out of the flow, *box* no longer has any inline content, meaning its text cursor is at the center, and it doesn't need to center anything. Its "job" is done.
- But since *thumb* is inline-block, it's *original* position is still based on *box*'s text cursor position (the center), meaning that when we make it `position: absolute`, its left edge will be placed at that center. It's not horizontally centered inside *box*, because from *box*'s point of view, there are no children in its flow that *need* centering.

This is halfways to a chicken and egg problem, so Chrome seems to get confused when it does a re-render of the page for the console.

This *explanation* may also be a bit confused, but you can see the result here - and even in this simple example, Chrome's console will do a reflow when you try to inspect it. In this example it even seems to enough to resize the window without opening the console (v17.0.963.56):

http://jsfiddle.net/h66Gj/

As far as I'm aware, the way it renders it first, is the way it's "meant to be" (last I checked, the W3C recommendations were vague about it, but at least Firefox agrees with the pre-inspect render).

There are many ways to get around it, my favorite being to only use `text-align: center` to center... text, and try to use e.g. `margin: auto` to center other content.

Comment: Nicely detailed answer. I will try your suggestion when I get back from work.

Comment: Thanks for this. Not exactly right in what you said but I got it. Removed text align center and used absolute positioning to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to tell, but it looks like it might be something to do with the interaction between the styling of the elements with class `ngg-gallery-thumbnail`. I would try tweaking/simplifying that. Do you need the `display:inline-block` setting there, for example?